# How to quote a sentence from other place in beamer?

Tags: beamer, quoting

i want to quote following sentence in my beamer in very standard way :

> we discuss the ambiguities of existing security definitions and then provide a general framework for defining AKE security when involve strong adversary capabilities.

how do i do with it? better have a example thanks

Comment: What about reading Section 12.11 in the »[beamer](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beamer)« user guide?

Answer (score 8):

You can use environment `quote` or `quotation` for multi paragraph quotations.

Because you have to quote only one paragraph you can use:

```
\begin{quote}<⟨action specification⟩>
  we discuss the ambiguities of existing security definitions and then 
  provide a  general framework for defining AKE security when involve 
  strong adversary capabilities.
\end{quote}
```

Change `⟨action specification⟩` to what you need.